# Which HTTP Response Status to Return

Tags: java, rest, http-status-codes

I have a REST operation. User wants to delete an object.

- If a database error occurs
- When writing to response with `response.getWriter()` if IOException occurs.

Which status code(500, 503 etc.) should I return to the client side.(I mean which one is more convenient?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

500 sounds most appropriate here, unless you *know* it's due to server overload.

If `response.getWriter()` (or a later call to the writer) throws an `IOException`, then I suspect you're beyond the stage of being able to usefully affect the response received by the client anyway...

Comment: @kamaci: Yes - the client usually shouldn't even know or care what the backend technology is, let alone which bit failed.

Comment: @JonSkeet  If the database produces a error due to a referential integrity constraint then it is a problem that is solvable by the client and therefore should be a 400 error.

Comment: @DarrelMiller: I would hope that would be detected and handled separately, but I agree in principle - 500 really should be for "what you asked for was fine, but I failed to honour it".

Comment: @JonSkeet  Agreed on defn of 500.  However, even if the RI constraint failure was wrapped by the DB layer and rethrown as something like NotAllowedToDeleteException when it goes across HTTP it needs to be a 4XX status code.  The server is saying "You should not be asking me to do that"

Comment: @DarrelMiller: Sure. And I certainly agree that it's not always as easy to tell as we might like... it's lovely when you *can* validate a client request before propagating it any further, but transactionality etc can make that a headache...

Answer (score 1):

There isn't that many 500 codes, and most of them have a [meaning](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) other than "database failed"/"ioexception occured". Note that you should probably distinguish between what kind of database error, e.g. deleting a non existant object (remember to check the "affected rows" of your DELETE statement), would result in a 404 status.

For your two examples, you should return status 500. Though if an IO exception occur on the response.getWriter(), it's likely too late to return an error, or you can't reach the client anyhow.

And, take a look at the response codes used by the [twitter api](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/error-codes-responses) as well as [this](http://restpatterns.org/HTTP_Status_Codes) page.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a temporary error, 503 is appropriate as it generally means "retry later". I don't think most database errors fall into that category though. In most cases a generic 500 is the best response. There aren't many options in the 500 list:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error

If it's an error due to the delete being an invalid operation or something like that, 403 forbidden is what I'd use :)

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided us with sufficient information to be able to answer the question regarding database errors.  If the database error is caused due to violating a referential integrity constraint then you should be returning a 400 error because it is an error on the part of the client.

What kind of database errors are you concerned about?

Comment: i.e. errors while trying to querying database, trying to connect database